# Best way to get a unique id for a machine - NSIS

Tags: nsis

I wish to create a unique id for a machine using NSIS ,

I did some research accross the web and found out a great solution written in c#

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer

Is there some known library/plugin/code that gives me a similar / close result ?

If not, what would be the best way to implement this type of solution?

Answer (score 2):

There  is an example of [generating a GUID with NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Create_a_GUID,_a_Globally_Unique_Identifier) on the wiki (actually 3 successive methods) that does not need external dependancy other than a system dll.

In short, it does not use the system management like the code you mentioned, but directly call the `CoCreateGuid()` function from ole32.

System accessor: it can automatically pop the stack into the variable you give it, or keep it on the stack

```
Function CreateGUID
  System::Call 'ole32::CoCreateGuid(g .s)'
FunctionEnd
```

Helper macro:

```
!define CreateGUID `!insertmacro _CreateGUID`
!macro _CreateGUID _RetVar
    Call CreateGUID
    !if ${_RetVar} != s
        Pop ${_RetVar}
    !endif
!macroend
```

Examples:

```
;${CreateGUID} $0 ; $0 contains GUID (poped from the stack by the macro)

;${CreateGUID} s ; the value is kept on the stack, we pop it ourselves
;Pop $0 ;contains GUID
```

Comment: This gives me a GUID for that machine in that current time, what if i want a guid for that machine (so if i ran the same method again i would get the same GUID ? )

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568(v=vs.85).aspx -> "To a very high degree of certainty, this function returns a unique value – no other invocation, on the same or any other system (networked or not), should return the same value" -> i want the same system to give the same invocation ...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to compile that code, embed the exe into your installer, and run the exe when your installer is running.